# Merging JavaScript arrays based on index without .concat

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to combine two arrays and most of the answers relate to adding the second array to the end of the first. I need to merge index to index.

Here's example code:

```js
let arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'];
let arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3'];

Array.prototype.zip = function (arr) {
  return this.map(function (e, i) {
    return [ e, arr[i]];
  })
};
const arr3 = arr1.zip(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

The result should be:

```
['golf', 'player1', 'hockey', 'player2', 'tennis', 'player3']
```

The above code looks like it should work but doesn't. If it can be fixed, or exchanged for better that would be great.....

Comment: Please don't mutate the built-in objects.

Comment: Okay, just to add - the end result I need is this ['golf', 'player1', 'hockey', 'player2', 'tennis', 'player3']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to zip both arrays:

```js
let arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'],
    arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3'];

let zip = (a1, a2) => a1.reduce((a, c, i) => (a.push(c, a2[i]), a), []);

console.log(zip(arr1, arr2));
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [`Comma Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: I realised that I gave the wrong example object which massively affects the result. So i'm calling this answer correct because it's the first answer given that works according to the incorrect info I gave. I wrote a new question on stackoverflow link here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921853/merging-a-simple-array-with-a-more-complex-one-without-concat-for-react-app

Answer (score 0):

`.map` maps an array to another array *one-to-one*: if you have 3 elements in the original array, `.map` can only ever produce another array that has 3 elements. If you can't use `concat`, use `.reduce` instead of `.map`, that way you can push multiple elements in a single iteration:

```js
const arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'];
const arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']

Array.prototype.zip = function (otherArr) {
  return this.reduce((accum, item, i) => {
    accum.push(item);
    accum.push(otherArr[i]);
    return accum;
  }, []);
};
const arr3 = arr1.zip(arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

Of course, it would be much better not to change the built-in Array object. You could easily avoid that by using a standalone function instead:

```js
const arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'];
const arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']

function zip(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((accum, item, i) => {
    accum.push(item);
    accum.push(arr2[i]);
    return accum;
  }, []);
};
const arr3 = zip(arr1, arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp array instead of direct input method.

```
let arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'];
let arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']

Array.prototype.zip = function (arr) {
    this.map(function (e, i) { this.splice(i*2+1, 0, arr[i]); }, this )
};
const arr3 = arr1.zip(arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Oh, it looks more clean.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix: 
Just flatten what you have now with a simple reduce():

```
let arr1 = ['golf', 'hockey', 'tennis'];
let arr2 = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']

Array.prototype.zip = function (arr) {
      return this.map(function (e, i) {
          return [ e, arr[i]]
      }).reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b)); // blink and you miss the change...
    };
const arr3 = arr1.zip(arr2)
console.log(arr3)
```

This approach preserves what you have and doesn't add a lot of complexity like extra method calls, temp arrays, etc; that's the beauty of the functional approach: you're one chain link away from what you need. I would also convert it to a stand-along method instead of modding the prototype, but that's aside the point...